# My get_context_data doesn't pass context to HTML properly when using Ajax

Tags: django

I'm trying to get a value from HTML to Django CBV, so I used Ajax. By the code `self.request.GET.get('tab_keyword')`, I got a value from HTML and I put it in `context['keyword']`. When I checked the value with {{ keyword }} on HTML, it shows nothing. I also double checked `tab_keyword` prints out a value on the console.

To debug this, I manually put a string value in `context['keyword']`, and {{ keyword }} shows what I need properly. From the debugging, I became pretty sure there's something wrong in `self.request.GET.get('tab_keyword')` or my Ajax codes in HTML.

Can anyone help me about this issue?

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data()
    tab_keyword = self.request.GET.get('tab_keyword')

    if self.request.is_ajax():
        if tab_keyword == '#':
            tab_keyword = None
    else:
        tab_keyword = None

    context['keyword'] = tab_keyword 

    return context
```

**Ajax**

```
$('.load-more-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/',
      data: {
        tab_keyword: '#' + $('.nav-link.active.show').html(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
      },
      success:function() {}
    })
  })
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.StoreListView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Comment: `tab_keyword = self.request.GET.get('tab_keyword') print(tab_keyword, self.request.is_ajax()) ` see feedback

Comment: @Ykh It prints "None True"

Comment: can you post you ajax code and full view and url code?

Comment: @Ykh Updated the post!

Comment: answer is update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax use `POST` method then you should use `tab_keyword = self.request.POST.get('tab_keyword')` in `get_context_data`

Comment: I was testing something and forgot changing it before posting it here

Comment: that‘s fine,everyone will can make simple mistakes

Answer (score -1):

What if I want to get `tab_keyword` from html to Django, I will suggest as follows,

view.py

```
def get_context_data(request):
    tab_keyword = request.GET['tab_keyword']
    # do something...
return JsonResponse(mydict)
```

hope it can help.